# date_select save higher day of the month available

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple datetime attribute to pick a date like this on the views

```
= f.date_select :period_end_at, default: { day: 31 }
```

It defaults to last day of the month as the example. The problem is that if month selected is "June" that has 30 days, since there is no '31' day for June, it will save the object as day 1 instead of day 30.

Is there an easy way to always save to the highest day of the month if the value provided is above all available for that moonth?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it could be shortened, but this should work (if I understood your question correctly):

```
= f.date_select :period_end_at, default: { day: Time.days_in_month(Time.now.month) }
```

Comment: But this code assumes that we're always on current month. The date_select month value could by any month.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [js snippet](https://gist.github.com/kpfefferle/1928544), it works well for me with Rails 4.2.0

```
<script>
$(function(){
  railsMonthDates();
  $("select[id*=_2i], select[id*=_1i]").change( railsMonthDates );
});

function railsMonthDates() {
  $("select[id*=_2i]").each(function(){
    $monthSelect = $(this);
    $daySelect = $(this).siblings("select[id*=_3i]");
    $yearSelect = $(this).siblings("select[id*=_1i]");

    var year = parseInt($yearSelect.val());
    var month = parseInt($monthSelect.val());
    var days = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();

    var selectedDay = $daySelect.val()
    $daySelect.html('');
    for(var i=1; i<=days; i++) {
      $daySelect.append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
    }
    $daySelect.val(selectedDay);
  });
}
</script>
```

Simply paste it into the partial which has the form. 
Pay attention, it match every element which has `id*=_1i`, `id*=_2i` or `id*=_3i`, so if you have more `f.date_select` you need to specify a better matcher.